# Contact us form isn't sending all populated fields to email, only a few? PHP AJAX JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, contact-form

So I've gone through a thread that helped me build this contact us form, but it talked about validating and making the fields required. There are two fields I have in my form that doesn't need to be required `$organization` and `$budget`, I can't seem to get the information in there to send with the email. The email shows those fields as blank but the other fields are populated.

I have practically zero experience in PHP outside of this form.

Expected output:

```
Name: xxx
Email: xxx@xxx.com
Organization: xxx
Budget: xxx
Message: xxx
```

What I actually receive in my email:

```
Name: xxx
Email: xxx@xxx.com
Organization:
Budget:
Message: xxx
```

Code:

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// Organization
    $organization = $_POST["organization"];


// Budget
    $budget = $_POST["budget"];


// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "example@mydomain.com";
$Subject = "Received msg from WIP contact form";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Organization: ";
$Body .= $organization;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Budget: ";
$Body .= $budget;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Sorry, something went wrong.";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="organization" class="h4">Organization</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization" placeholder="Enter organization">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form group col-sm-6">
            <label for="budget" class="h4">Budget</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="budget" placeholder="$50000">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="h4">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="button pull-right ">Submit</button>
    <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Please fill in the required fields.");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var organization = $("#organization").val();
    var budget = $("#budget").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message + "&organization=" + organization + "&budget" + budget,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}


function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "We'll be in touch with you soon!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

***EDIT***

Thanks to Uxmal for suggesting the `name="xxxx"` in the input field. He said that by doing this, the `$_POST` is looking for inputs with `name`. Which made me realise I must be doing something else wrong. Turns out my ajax was poorly written and I was also missing the `<form action` aswell. Below is the corrected version of the form and ajax code.

```
<form action="form-process.php" method="POST" role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <label for="organization" class="h4">Organization</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization" name="organization" placeholder="Enter organization name">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form group col-sm-6">
            <label for="budget" class="h4">Budget</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="budget" name="budget" placeholder="50000">
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="h4">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="button pull-right ">Submit</button>
    <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function submitForm(){

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/form-process.php",
    data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
    success: function(text) {
        if (text == "success") {
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false, text);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: also add html form

Comment: Please add your html form with inputs data for this script like <input type="text" name="organization"><input type="text" name="budget">

Comment: hi @Smartpal I've added the html and JS

Comment: hi @uxmal I've added the html and js, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You PHP code at line

```
// Organization
$organization = $_POST["organization"];
// Budget
$budget = $_POST["budget"];
```

looks for inputs with **name**: organization and budget, no to for **id** organization and budget.

At you html is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization" placeholder="Enter organization">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="budget" placeholder="$50000">
```

without a tag: name="organization" and tag: name="budget".

So put those tags like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization" name="organization" placeholder="Enter organization">
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="budget" name="budget" placeholder="$50000">
```

and then your PHP code will get the data.

Comment: for other inputs please do the same name tags

Comment: Hi Uxmal, thanks for your reply, I gave it a shot but it doesn't seem to work. The other fields do show up (without specifying a name tag).

Comment: ... do the same for other inputs - put the name tags with the right names

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>

Comment: PHP $_POST['var_name'] looks for <input name="var_name"> not for id="var_name"

Comment: ... and force post method **method="post"** at form config like <form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake" method="post">

Comment: So I did what you asked, didn't work. I thought the whole point of using Ajax type: POST was so that I didn't need to use method=post in the form. Also my variables are being passed through from the JS not from the HTML, maybe that's why?

Comment: Hi Uxmal, so I looked more into how you had me structure it and I see how that way is simpler and then I can use `$('#contactForm').serialize()` to shorten it on ajax! so thanks for that. Unfortunately I still can't seem to get the form to pass the organization and budget information with the rest.

Comment: yeahh!!! i figured it out. All thanks to your suggestion name="name", posting what i changed above.